# Confusion regarding a few sign conventions in appyling faraday's law to inductive circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, conventions, path-integral, electromagnetic-induction

In the mit ocw lecture by Prof. Lewin on EMI, He quotes a few statements [from here to couple of seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2micky_3uI&t=637s) of the lecture.

I am confused why the sign of  $L\frac{dI}{dt}$ changes, when we go around and evaluate the closed loop integral in the opposite direction of the current.

By faraday's law , we have

$$\oint_{+\partial \Sigma} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{\ell} = - \frac{d}{dt} \int_{+\Sigma} \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A}$$

This seemingly suggest that the negative sign would be only affected by the dot product $\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A}$ , and indeed, the direction of the $d\vec{A}$(Area vector) is only affected by the *sense* of path chosen for $d\vec{\ell}$ .

Then, what might be the role of current (*not the time derivative of current*) in deciding the sign of  $L\frac{dI}{dt}$ ?

If I had made any wrong statement here, please do correct it. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, i just noticed a really simple solution for my question. The answer is not about the physics itself, but *absence of mind* , **The current indeed decides the direction of magnetic field**

I still have a doubt on the conclusion that whether the **Area vector convention** is **strictly** necessary for the thing which prof. Lewin mentions, as far as i tried, it is indeed necessary..